# jQuery Flot Animator plotanimator is Not a Method

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, flot

I'm working with jQuery Flot Animator currently and am trying to animate a simple line graph.  I am receiving the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Object function (e,n){return new x.fn.init(e,n,t)}
>   has no method 'plotanimator' testflot.html:17 (anonymous function)
>   testflot.html:17 x.event.dispatch jquery.js:4676 y.handle

jQuery is loaded as well as the flot and animator files so I'm really not sure what's going on.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="libraries/flot/jquery.flot.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="libraries/flot/jquery.flot.animator.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="chart" style="width: 500px; height: 300px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function () {

var d8 = [[2, 5],[4, 8],[6, 2],[7, 5],[9,1],[10, 4],[12, 5],[13, 6],[14, 4]];
$.plotanimator($("#chart"), [{ data : d8, animator: { start: 100, steps: 99, duration: 1000, direction: "left" } }]);
 //$.plot($("#chart"), [{data:d8}]);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Did some digging around in the jquery.flot.animator.js file and discovered that while the directions of the author's site say to use .plotanimator, it really should be .plotAnimator.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 
    $.plotanimator
should be:
    $.plotAnimator